# Show source code in HTML / wysiwyg editor in Events

Tags: civievent, ckeditor

The source code button is missing from certain areas, such as event summary and event description. Any ideas on how to access it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have different config for ckeditor for civievent. See https://yoursite.org/civicrm/admin/ckeditor?preset=civievent. (Replace `yoursite` with your actual site.)

Comment: Thanks!  Even though we have CKEditor enabled, I think our events might be using TinyMCE because the wysiwyg ribbon doesn't match the settings I'm seeing in the ckeditor config

Comment: actually I think the issue is that link brings me to the config for CKEditor4 and the default (in admin/customize data/display preferences) is set to CKEditor5.  Is there a different link to the config for 5?

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Looking at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/ckeditor5 it says `a niche feature of ckeditor4 was a UI for configuration. The toolbar IS configured
through a javascript array so it would be possible to find a way to customise that
(but there is no current plan / demand for this)`. Another editor worth trying is summernote: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/summernote